# How to remove person's credit at end of period?

Tags: mysql

I have system in which customer get credit on any purchase.
Now I want to force remove this credit after every three month.
Like...if person have credits of **January February March**...Now when month April come It automatically delete credit of **January** month and recalculate for next 3 month.

**Here credit entries denotes that customer has bought something...so their account credited by few points.**

**Debit entries denoted that they used this credit as money in their orders**

I have table entries like below

---

```
              (cr_dr)      (cr_dr) 
               Credit        Debit

(created_on)       
Jan             10            00

                00            05

(created_on)
Feb             10            00

                00            05                    

                00            07
(created_on)
Mar             10            00

                00            03

                00            07
(created_on)
Apr             10            00
```

for case of months january,february,March

```
Total Credits(for last 3 months only ) = Total Credit - Total Debit

                                     3 =  30 - 27
```

This 3 credits will go to next month(**April**) but how to remove first month(**January**) credits from it.

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'Credit' THEN amount END,0)) - 
SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN cr_dr = 'Debit' THEN amount END,0)) balance 
FROM cb_customer_credit_log WHERE coupon_assignee = "1"  AND    created_on >= now() - interval 3 month ")
```

Comment: What you have tried? please show us your code

Comment: I don't understand how these are 'table entries'. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking, what does your desired outcome look like?AND you should make your sample data resemble your code, the sample data is too simplified to be useful.AND what do you mean 'remove this credit' - do you mean zeroise or delete the data for january?

Comment: Yes delete data of January and recalculate for February,March,April.

Comment: So first entry for feb becomes plus 15 cr, first entry for mar becomes plus 13 cr first entry for apr becomes becomes plus 13 cr? Can the debits ever be more than the credits or can user only spend what is in credit?

Comment: first entry for feb becomes plus 5(10-5) cr only ....like carry forward..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this.

```
date(now() - interval 3 month)
```

This code calculates date and time records that is only within 3 months only. In a literal sense that is 90 days back, irregardless of 29,30,31 days per  month.  If you started 9th this month, you end up 9th to the past. Makes things easier.

now()  is the current system time.
interval 3 month  ... is the command to calculate turn back 3 months from the current system time.
That entire line you have to pair it to a condition   >=   (greater or equal to)

example:

```
activitydatetime >= date(now() - interval 3 month)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but for some case it goes into minus.Like for first 3 month it (total credit - total debit) = 3 where as if you calculate with same formula for last three month then (total credit - total debit) = 7...is it right ?

Comment: perhaps try extend 4 months and observe again.  Im not sure what you try to achieve, but it could be your own criteria of your system.